# Render own partial via javascript in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, renderpartial

Say there is a partial called _hello_world.html.erb

```
<% if toggle %>
    HELLO WORLD ON
    <%= link_to "Turn it off", what_should_come_here %>
<% else %>
    HELLO WORLD OFF
    <%= link_to "Turn it on", what_should_come_here %>
<% end %>
```

Intially this partial will be called from say an index file like this,

```
<%= render :partial => 'test/hello_world', :locals => {:toggle => true} %>
```

But after I click the toggle link it should switch between On and Off states which should basically render the own partial again overriding the previous partial. How to do this ?

Note: I have given the Question in http://sscce.org/ format.

Comment: you want to load the index again or just want to change the contains of this partial ???

Comment: @dku.rajkumar : Mr.DKU, just change the partial contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `link_to` it would be better to use `link_to_remote`

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="toggle_div">
  <%= render :partial => 'test/hello_world', :locals => {:toggle => @toggle} %>
</div>
```

**_hello_world.html.erb**

```
<% if toggle %>
    HELLO WORLD ON
    <%= link_to_remote "Turn it off", my_action_path(:toggle => toggle) %>
<% else %>
    HELLO WORLD OFF
    <%= link_to_remote "Turn it on", my_action_path(:toggle => toggle) %>
<% end %>
```

**in action**

```
def myaction
   value = params[:toggle]
   // do something with toggle value

   @toggle = value == "true" ? false: true
   render :update do |page|
     page.replace_html 'toggle_div', :partial => 'hello_world', :locals => {:toggle => @toggle}
   end
end
```